# Get Java's list iterator to return something other than Object

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

I use Java.

I already have a class for a custom object called "Subject".

I have another class that only contains a Linked List of Subject objects. (called subjectsList)

I wrote one of the methods (called "getSubject()") in the subjectsList class that is meant to return the Subject object at a specific index in the Linked List. To do this, I used a ListIterator. I would create a ListIterator at a given index in the LinkedList and use the .next() method.

However, the .next() method in a ListIterator only returns a java.lang.Object, even though I want it to return a Subject object.

**How do I get ListIterator.next() to return a Subject object?**

I've tried downcasting to a Subject but this seems to fail, and I read somewhere that you can't downcast unrelated objects.

This is my subjectsList class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class subjectsList
{
    //my LinkedList of Subject objects and a ListIterator
    private LinkedList<Subject> l;
    private ListIterator itr;

    //constructor that simply creates a new empty LinkedList
    public subjectsList()
    {
        l = new LinkedList();
    }

    //Method to return the Subject object at a specific index in the LinkedList
    public Subject getSubject( byte index )
    {
        itr = l.listIterator( index );
        return itr.next();
    }

    //Method to add a new Subject object to the LinkedList
    public void addSubject( String nameInput, byte levelInput )
    {
        l.addLast( new Subject( nameInput, levelInput ) );
    }

    //Method to remove the Subject object at a specific index in the LinkedList
    public void removeSubject( byte index )
    {
        itr = l.listIterator( index );
        itr.next();
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

The method in question is the "getSubject()" method.

Comment: In java it is the convention to start class names with a capital letter. That also makes it easier for other people to read your code.

Comment: Why do you actually need that `ListIterator`? What's wrong with `List.get(index)` and `List.remove(index)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare your iterator as :

```
private ListIterator<Subject> itr;
```

Also create your LinkedList object as follows in constructor:

```
l = new LinkedList<Subject>();
```

You could also cast it to Subject while returning as your list only stores Subject object. But it would be better to define Iterator as said earlier.

```
public Subject getSubject( byte index )
{
    itr = l.listIterator( index );
    return (Subject)itr.next();
}
```

Other than your problem I see naming convention problem in your code. It is better to follow it and make a habbit.

NOTE: I have made changes to my answer after trying your example in Eclipse IDE. I would suggest you to use IDE as it would also show you warning about such things.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out...I didn't know that naming conventions were so important >.<

Changed class name now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use genericity with your [`ListIterator`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

```
private ListIterator<Subject> itr;
```

Now `itr.next()` return subjects.

**Resources :**

- [Oracle's tutorial on Collections - Iterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html#Iterator)

PS: I suggest that you change the instantiation of your `LinkedList` into `l = new LinkedList<Subject>();`

Comment: It is also worth noting that a lot of Java compilers will produce a warning for `private ListIterator itr;` about using raw types.

Comment: Oh forgot about the <Subject> in the constructor...Thanks!